# How to make a query using columns of a JoinTable in Rest Webservice with netbeans

Tags: java, database, rest

How I can to do this query:
`@NamedQuery(name = "Scuser.findFriends", query = "SELECT s FROM Scuser s, friends f WHERE f.firstid = :iduser and s.iduser = f.secondid")`

in this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "scuser")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
 @NamedQuery(name = "Scuser.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM Scuser s"),
 @NamedQuery(name = "Scuser.findByIduser", query = "SELECT s FROM Scuser s WHERE s.iduser = :iduser"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Scuser.findByUpassword", query = "SELECT s FROM Scuser s WHERE s.upassword = :upassword"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Scuser.findByUname", query = "SELECT s FROM Scuser s WHERE s.uname = :uname"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Scuser.findByTpoints", query = "SELECT s FROM Scuser s WHERE s.tpoints = :tpoints"),
//    @NamedQuery(name = "Scuser.findFriends", query = "SELECT s FROM Scuser s, friends f WHERE f.firstid = :iduser and s.iduser = f.secondid"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Scuser.findByUnameUpassword", query = "SELECT s FROM Scuser s WHERE s.uname = :uname and s.upassword = :upassword")})
public class Scuser implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 2147483647)
    @Column(name = "iduser")
    private String iduser;
    @Size(max = 200)
    @Column(name = "upassword")
    private String upassword;
    @Size(max = 200)
    @Column(name = "uname")
    private String uname;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Column(name = "tpoints")
    private Double tpoints;
    @JoinTable(name = "friends", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "firstid", referencedColumnName = "iduser")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "secondid", referencedColumnName = "iduser")})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Scuser> scuserCollection;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "scuserCollection")
    private Collection<Scuser> scuserCollection1;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "scuserCollection")
    private Collection<Beach> beachCollection;

public Scuser() {
}

public Scuser(String iduser) {
    this.iduser = iduser;
}

public String getIduser() {
    return iduser;
}

public void setIduser(String iduser) {
    this.iduser = iduser;
}

public String getUpassword() {
    return upassword;
}

public void setUpassword(String upassword) {
    this.upassword = upassword;
}

public String getUname() {
    return uname;
}

public void setUname(String uname) {
    this.uname = uname;
}

public Double getTpoints() {
    return tpoints;
}

public void setTpoints(Double tpoints) {
    this.tpoints = tpoints;
}

@XmlTransient
public Collection<Scuser> getScuserCollection() {
    return scuserCollection;
}

public void setScuserCollection(Collection<Scuser> scuserCollection) {
    this.scuserCollection = scuserCollection;
}

@XmlTransient
public Collection<Scuser> getScuserCollection1() {
    return scuserCollection1;
}

public void setScuserCollection1(Collection<Scuser> scuserCollection1) {
    this.scuserCollection1 = scuserCollection1;
}

@XmlTransient
public Collection<Beach> getBeachCollection() {
    return beachCollection;
}

public void setBeachCollection(Collection<Beach> beachCollection) {
    this.beachCollection = beachCollection;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (iduser != null ? iduser.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Scuser)) {
        return false;
    }
    Scuser other = (Scuser) object;
    if ((this.iduser == null && other.iduser != null) || (this.iduser != null && !this.iduser.equals(other.iduser))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "REST.Scuser[ iduser=" + iduser + " ]";
}
```

}

Comment: As you realized, this query is invalid. So it's hard to tell what you want to do, given that the query is invalid and we thus don't know what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I want to do a query like that, but I don't how to aces to the joinTable friends an to the join columns of it. Because when I create the restful web service with a database in the netbeans it only create the classes  of the tables that no are relations.

Comment: You can't access the fields of a join table, and you don't need to. Why don't you explain what you want the query to return?

Comment: I want the query returns me the user who are friends to each others.

Comment: The users who have the secondid matching with the firstid passed as iduser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have the ID of a user, and you want to get the friends of the user identified by this ID. The easiest way is to do

```
Scuser user = em.find(User.class, userId);
Collection<Scuser> friends = user.getScuserCollection();
```

If you want to do it using a JPQL query, you just need

```
select friend from Scuser user 
inner join user.scuserCollection friend
where user.id = :userId
```

Note that your mapping isn't right: scuserCollection1 and beachCollection are both mapped by the same attribute. You should also choose better names for your associations (like `friends` for example, instead of `scuserCollection`).

Comment: Thank you very much. The first code works perfectly, changing "User.class" for "Scuser.class" . The second I can't do it work.